# Distinct Values in XSL1.0

Tags: xslt

I need to convert the following into XSL 1.0 compatibility

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(/ChangeLog/ChangeSets//WorkItems//WorkItem/_ID))"/>
```

Have tried

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/ChangeLog/ChangeSets//WorkItems//WorkItem/_ID[not(.=following::_ID)])"/>
```

Here is the sample XML

```
<ChangeLog>
<ChangeSets>
<ChangeSet>
  <ID>31</ID>
  <Date>10/30/2012 2:05:59 AM</Date>
  <Comment />
  <User>XXX</User>
  <WorkItems>
    <WorkItem>
             <_ID>2</_ID>
      <_AreaID>1</_AreaID>
      <_AuthorizedAs>XXX</_AuthorizedAs>
    </WorkItem>
  </WorkItems>
</ChangeSet>
<ChangeSet>
  <ID>12</ID>
  <Date>9/18/2012 7:30:43 AM</Date>
  <Comment />
  <User>XXX</User>
  <WorkItems>
    <WorkItem>

      <_ID>1</_ID>
      <_AreaID>1</_AreaID>
      <_AuthorizedAs>XXX</_AuthorizedAs>
    </WorkItem>
    <WorkItem>

      <_ID>2</_ID>
      <_AreaID>1</_AreaID>
      <_AuthorizedAs>XXX</_AuthorizedAs>
    </WorkItem>
  </WorkItems>
</ChangeSet>
<ChangeSet>
<ChangeSets>
</ChangeLog>
```

Here is the XSLT for the same .Mind this is in XSL 2.0 . I need it converted to XSL 1.0 and hence the question . I have updated the stylesheet version alone to point to XSL 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/ChangeLog">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Release Notes Generated from TFS</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .HeaderColumnStyle
      {
      width: 566px;
      border: None;
      }
      .DataColumnStyle
      {
      border: none; width:auto;
      white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */
      white-space: -pre-wrap; /* ancient Opera */
      white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* newer Opera */
      white-space: pre-wrap; /* Chrome; W3C standard */
      word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
      }
      .DescriptionDataColumnStyle
      {
      border: none;
      width: 850px;
      white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */
      white-space: -pre-wrap; /* ancient Opera */
      white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* newer Opera */
      white-space: pre-wrap; /* Chrome; W3C standard */
      word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
      }
      .style1
      {
      border-style: none;
      border-color: inherit;
      border-width: medium;
      width: 60px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 align="center"> TFS Change Log Report</h1>
    <table frame="box" border="3" style="width: 100%; border-bottom:#000080       outset;border-left:#000080 outset;border-top:#000080 outset;border-right:#000080 outset; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
      <tr>
        <td class="HeaderColumnStyle">
          <b>
            <xsl:text>TFS Server : </xsl:text>
          </b>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="TFSServer/node()"/>
        </td>
        <td class="HeaderColumnStyle">
          <b>
            <xsl:text>Project Name : </xsl:text>
          </b>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="TFSProjectName/node()"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="HeaderColumnStyle">
          <b>
            <xsl:text>Branch Location : </xsl:text>
          </b>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="TFSProjectBranchName/node()"/>
        </td>
        <td class="HeaderColumnStyle">
          <b>
            <xsl:text>Report Produced By : </xsl:text>
          </b>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ReportProducedBy/node()"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="HeaderColumnStyle">
          <b>
            <xsl:text>From Changeset : </xsl:text>
          </b>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="FromChangeSet/node()"/>
        </td>
        <td class="HeaderColumnStyle">
          <b>
            <xsl:text>To Changeset : </xsl:text>
          </b>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ToChangeSet/node()"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="HeaderColumnStyle">
          <b>
            <xsl:text>Total Number of Changesets : </xsl:text>
          </b>
          <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(/ChangeLog//ChangeSet/ID))"/>
        </td>
        <td class="HeaderColumnStyle">
          <b>
            <xsl:text>Total Number of Work Items : </xsl:text>
          </b>
          <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(/ChangeLog/ChangeSets//WorkItems//WorkItem/_ID))"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="HeaderColumnStyle">
          <b>
            <xsl:text>Changesets with associated Work Items : </xsl:text>
          </b>
          <xsl:value-of select="count(/ChangeLog//ChangeSet[WorkItems/WorkItem/_ID[1] > 0])"/>
        </td>
        <td class="HeaderColumnStyle">
          <b>
            <xsl:text>Changesets without associated Work Items : </xsl:text>
          </b>
          <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(/ChangeLog//ChangeSet/ID)) - count(/ChangeLog//ChangeSet[WorkItems/WorkItem/_ID[1] > 0])"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="HeaderColumnStyle" colspan="2">
          <b>
            <xsl:text>Report Date : </xsl:text>
          </b>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ReportDate/node()"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this several times to select distinct values when doing search engine related products:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="_ID" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/path/to/iterate[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', .)[1])]">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think it will work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks , but the <xsl:output> and <xsl:key> is encountering issues when enclosed within the <td> element. The whole snippet is like this '<td class="HeaderColumnStyle"> <b> <xsl:text>Total Number of Work Items : </xsl:text> </b> <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(/ChangeLog/ChangeSets//WorkItems//WorkItem/_ID))"/> </td>'

Comment: @Alfaromeo - your comment doesn't make sense. The solution provided here is the appropriate XSLT 1.0 method for finding distinct nodes. If you could update your answer with a sample complete XML input, we can assist further.

Comment: Don't enclose the `<xsl:output>` or `<xsl:key>` elements within that `<td>`. They should be at the top of your stylesheet; in your case, they should be right below the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element.

Comment: Thank you, but <xsl:template match="/"> too throws error.The basic idea is to show the cumulative count of the distinct values within after the </b> tag

Comment: Then I suspect you have an open tag or something somewhere that is making it invalid XML/XSLT. There is no reason (that I can think of), that the template node should be throwing any kinds of error. What are you using as a parser?

Comment: Thanks, the code is just appending the value in the node . I need the total count .Say if the _ID value in one iteration is 2 and the next is 1 it shows "21" . But actually it should be 2

Answer (score 2):

Dave Pawson's XSLT FAQs are an invaluable source.  Thanks Mr. Pawson!  Here's some code ideas for "duplicates."  http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N2696.html

The whole collection starts at http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/sect21.html